# How to create columns from a list in a for loop using mutate

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dplyr

I was wondering if there was a way to create multiple columns from a list in R using the `mutate()` function within a for loop.

Here is an example of what I mean:

**The Problem:**

I have a data frame `df` that has 2 columns: category and rating. I want to add a column for every element of `df$category` and in that column, I want a 1 if the category column matches the iterator.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  category = c("Art","Technology","Finance"),
  rating = c(100,95,50)
)
```

Doing it manually, I could do:

```
df <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(art = ifelse(category == "Art", 1,0))
```

However, what happens when I have 50 categories? (Which is close to what I have in my original problem. That would take a lot of time!)

**What I tried:**

```
category_names <- df$category

for(name in category_names){

  df <-
    df %>% 
    mutate(name = ifelse(category == name, 1,0))

}
```

Unfortunately, It doesn't seem to work.

I'd appreciate any light on the subject!

Full Code:

```
library(dplyr)

#Creates tibble
df <- tibble(
  category = c("Art","Technology","Finance"),
  rating = c(100,95,50)
)

#Showcases the operation I would like to loop over df
df <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(art = ifelse(category == "Art", 1,0))

#Creates a variable for clarity
category_names <- df$category

#For loop I tried
for(name in category_names){

  df <-
    df %>% 
    mutate(name = ifelse(category == name, 1,0))

}
```

I am aware that what I am essentially doing is a form of `model.matrix()`; however, before I found out about that function I was still perplexed why what I was doing before wasn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` after creating a sequence column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number(), n = 1) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = n, 
             values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  rating   Art Technology Finance
#   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    100     1          0       0
#2     95     0          1       0
#3     50     0          0       1
```

---

Or another option is `map`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfc(unique(df$category),  ~  df %>%
                                 transmute(!! .x := +(category == .x))) %>% 
     bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  category   rating   Art Technology Finance
#* <chr>       <dbl> <int>      <int>   <int>
#1 Art           100     1          0       0
#2 Technology     95     0          1       0
#3 Finance        50     0          0       1
```

---

If we need a `for` loop

```
for(name in category_names) df <- df %>% mutate(!! name := +(category == name))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `table`

```
cbind(df, as.data.frame.matrix(table(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$category)))
#    category rating Art Finance Technology
#1        Art    100   1       0          0
#2 Technology     95   0       0          1
#3    Finance     50   0       1          0
```

Comment: My first thought was to use `pivot_wider()` but was unable to really wrap my head around it; however, with the original question being using mutate and for-loops this seems like a workaround. I'm curious to see an answer within the realm of the question. Thank you for your speedy response!

Comment: I edited my previous comment to reflect the reasoning. I was so excited about a response and saw `pivot_wider` and hastily made the decision to accept it. My apologies for that.

Comment: @spookywagons not clear where it is not working.  I didn't see any new data on your post

Comment: As great as your solution is (and I do mean that), they are not using a `mutate()` within a `for` loop. I'm not trying to discredit your answer because that is one way I would have wanted to - however, I don't believe the subject question is answered.

Comment: @spookywagons let me know if you have an issue with using `:=` instead of `==`

Comment: @spookywagons it's okay.  Usually people wanted to avoid `for` loop when using tidyverse.  So, I was thinking about answering the other options instead of for loop

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to throw something in for anyone who stumbles across this question. The problem in the OP is that the "name" column name gets re-used during each iteration of the loop: you end up with only one new column, when you really wanted three (or 50). I consistently find myself wanting to create multiple new columns within loops, and I recently found out that mutate can now take "glue"-like inputs to do this. The following code now also solves the original question:

```
for(name in category_names){
  df <-
    df %>%
    mutate("{name}" := ifelse(category == name, 1, 0))
}
```

This is equivalent to akrun's answer using a for loop, but it doesn't involve the !! operator. Note that you still need the "walrus" := operator, and that the column name needs to be a string (I think since it's using "glue" in the background). I'm thinking some people might find this format easier to understand.

Reference: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/